# Conversion of time to hours worked

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have a column named "Duration" in my excel sheet that has time values in it. The column is as follows:

[Duration column in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EePRc.png)

This time actually represents the hours worked so for example: 8:00 is equal to 8 hours or 12:30 is equal to 12 hours and 30 minutes worked.

I am importing this data to PowerBI to add the hours and see who has worked the most hours. I converted the column to hours using the below code:

```
Hours accumulated = HOUR('Report'[Duration])
```

The issue I face here is that it converts the time into its hour equivalent i.e., 12:00 gets converted to zero whereas I need it as 12 to consider it as 12 hours.

Column in PowerBI:
[Duration column in PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2djn.png)

Hours calculated column in PowerBI:
[Hours column in PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBaoY.png)

Any help for the same would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your dutation column is showing a time not the amount of hours. You will need to adjust the format of the column.

Comment: https://dax.guide/hour/

Returns the hour as a number from 0 (12:00 A.M.) to 23 (11:00 P.M.)
when we look at your "Duration column in PowerBI" that we see all values have AM;
Also HOUR function don't give you a halfhours.

Comment: Is there a way I could get the output as if 12:30 PM then 12 hours and 30 mins? Instead of using the hour function. The reason I am doing this is so I can add the hours and get the total hours worked by each employee.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the answer. I simply used:

```
Column = 'Report'[Duration]*24
```

And this gave me the exact output I was looking for and works properly.